# How to debug groovy script using in live template?

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy, live-templates

i am new to groovy，i want to generate parameters comments like "@param [paramemter name] [parameter type] " for a method by live template.The predefined function "methodParameters()" can not do this,so i want run the custom grooy script  by predefined function "groovyScript".

The custom script named "test.groovy"  as follow:

```
def methodParameters=_1
def methodParameterTypes=_2
def result=''; 
def params=methodParameters.replaceAll('[\\\\[|\\\\]|\\\\s]', '').split(',').toList(); 
def type=methodParameterTypes.replaceAll('[\\\\[|\\\\]|\\\\s]', '').split(',').toList();
for(i = 0; i < params.size(); i++) {
    result+='* @param '+ params[i] + ' ' + type[i] + ((i < params.size() - 1) ? '\\n ' : '')
};
return result
```

and I call this this script by inline function "groovyScript" like this:

```
groovyScript("D:\project\groovyDemo\src\test.groovy",methodParameters(),methodParameterTypes())
```

but I got the error message as follow:

```
No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.replaceAll() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [[\\[|\\]|\\s], ]Possible solutions: replaceAll(java.util.function.UnaryOperator)
```

i can not find any ideas to **debug** this groovy script using in live template of Idea.Can anyone give me some advice?

---

**update**:

Question definition:

1. how to fix this error
2. the steps about how to debug the groovy script using the live template of IntelliJ IDEA if it produces other errors

For the second question,I asked the IntelliJ IDEA support for help.He said that I can fix errors by simulating scripts instead of debugging directly,but I do not know how to simulate it.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, but according to the error, `methodParameters` returns an array, and you're trying to call `replaceAll` on it. Are you trying to replaceAll in each *item* in that array?

Comment: Try using double quotes instead of single quotes for parameter strings.

Comment: @DaveNewton,yes.The original format of predefined function “methodParameters()” is "[a,b]",but I want to custom the format like"@param a int,@param b int".I have two questions about that,firstly I want to know how to fix it,secondly I want to know the steps about how to debug the groovy script if it produces other errors.For the second question，I asked the IntelliJ IDEA support for help.He said that I can fix errors by simulating scripts instead of debugging directly,but I do not know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
groovyScript("\"${_1}\"", methodParameters());
```

Answer (score 0):

because "methodParameters(),methodParameterTypes()" return a arrayList, it's not a String, so you can't call replaceAll method of String, you can try this: `methodParameters.toString().replaceAll('[\\\\[|\\\\]|\\\\s]', '').split(',').toList();`